# Access violation error occured while connecting to a remote server using php

Tags: php, post, curl, access-violation

I have the following code

```
<?php
function send_post($url,$data) {//sends data array(param=>val,...) to the page $url in post method and returns the reply string
    $post = http_build_query($data);
    $context = stream_context_create(array("http"=>array(
       "method" => "POST",
       "header" => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"."Content-Length: ". strlen($post) . "\r\nUser-agent:Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)r\n",  
       "content" => $post,
    ))); 
    $page = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    return $page;
}
$post_data=array();
$post_data['firstName'] = 'Name';
$post_data['lccp_trnno']='16348';
$post_data['lccp_month'] = '8';
$post_data['lccp_day']='12';
$post_data['lccp_srccode']='ktym';
$post_data['lccp_dstncode']='tvc';
$post_data['lccp_classopt']='1A';
$post_data['lccp_conc']='ZZZZZZ'; 
$post_data['lccp_age']='30';
echo send_post("http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_frenq_cgi.cgi",$post_data);
?>
```

The query results in a page with message

```
access violation, reason mask=!XB, virtual address=!XH, PC=!X
```

Obviously the problem is not with my code.The request creates some type of error in their page.Do anybody know what type of error is this and the reason for this,and how to do a working request avoiding the error?

Comment: That error is given for which line of code in your example?

Comment: The error is shown in the result of the query.The query is working..The above shown is the actual code and not an example

Comment: Use an http sniffer to see what a browser does if you do this through the 'normal' channels.

Comment: Okay, then what is your question? If you do not know how to successfully query the HTTP interface of indianrail.gov, please contact their technical support and ask for documentation. Because the PHP code you've posted here works and nobody can tell you what the issue on the server @ indianrail.gov is unless you post *that* code here.

Comment: Apart from that, there is not information about the string `access violation, reason mask=!XB, virtual address=!XH, PC=!X` on the internet at all. You should really contact technical support of that website. Just write them, ask what happened, say you were looking for a train and than see how they react. Maybe you learn more then.

Answer (score 1):

Use all the fields listed in the below answer including "classopt" and "lcp_frclass1"

```
 <FORM NAME="FareInfo" METHOD="POST" ACTION="http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin        /inet_frenq_cgi.cgi"><td>
 <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="lccp_submitfare" CLASS="btn_style" ONCLICK="return submitfare()"  VALUE="Get Fare">
 <INPUT  TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="lccp_trnno" SIZE="5" VALUE="12635">
 <INPUT  TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="lccp_srccode" SIZE="4" VALUE="MS  ">
 <INPUT  TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="lccp_dstncode" SIZE="4" VALUE="MDU ">
 <INPUT  TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="lccp_month" SIZE="2" VALUE="3">
 <INPUT  TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="lccp_day" SIZE="2" VALUE="8">
 <INPUT  TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="lccp_year" SIZE="4" VALUE="2013">
 <INPUT  TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="lccp_age" SIZE="2" VALUE="ADULT_AGE">
 <INPUT  TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="lccp_conc" SIZE="6" VALUE="ZZZZZZ">
 <INPUT  TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="lccp_classopt" SIZE="2" VALUE="ZZ">
 <INPUT  TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="lccp_frclass1" SIZE="2" VALUE="2S">
 <INPUT  TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="lccp_frclass2" SIZE="2" VALUE="ZZ">
 <INPUT  TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="lccp_frclass3" SIZE="2" VALUE="ZZ">
 <INPUT  TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="lccp_frclass4" SIZE="2" VALUE="ZZ">
 <INPUT  TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="lccp_frclass5" SIZE="2" VALUE="ZZ">
 <INPUT  TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="lccp_frclass6" SIZE="2" VALUE="ZZ">
 <INPUT  TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="lccp_frclass7" SIZE="2" VALUE="ZZ">
 <INPUT  TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="lccp_disp_avl_flg" SIZE="1" VALUE="1">
 <INPUT  TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="lccp_enrtcode" SIZE="4" VALUE="NONE">
 <INPUT  TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="lccp_viacode" SIZE="4" VALUE="NONE">
 </FORM>
```